# How to Merge Object into an Array in Javasript with Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this in javascript,

```
data = [
    {
        item: "Banana",
        path: "fruit"
    },
    {
        message: "Volvo",
        path: "car"
    },
    {
        message: "Cat",
        path: "animal"
    }
]
```

And I need to create new object like this,

```
data = {
    fruit: "Banana",
    car: "Volvo",
    animal: "Cat"
}
```

I've try this loop,

```
var newData = [];

data.map(value => {
    newData[value.path] = value.message
});
```

But this loop keep return like this,

```
data = [
    {
        fruit: "Banana"
    },
    {
        car: "Volvo"
    },
    {
        animal: "Cat"
    }
]
```

How to solve case like this?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.reduce`

```js
const data = [
  {
    item: 'Banana',
    path: 'fruit'
  },
  {
    message: 'Volvo',
    path: 'car'
  },
  {
    message: 'Cat',
    path: 'animal'
  }
]

const res = data.reduce((acc, el) => ({ ...acc, [el.path]: el.message || el.item }), {})

console.log(res)
```

Or continue with your solution, but change array `[]` to object `{}` instead

```js
const data = [
  {
    item: 'Banana',
    path: 'fruit'
  },
  {
    message: 'Volvo',
    path: 'car'
  },
  {
    message: 'Cat',
    path: 'animal'
  }
]

var newData = {}

data.map(value => {
  newData[value.path] = value.message || value.item
})

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize I forgot to change the type of initial new data. Good job!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Array.prototype.reduce` instead of `Array.prototype.map` :

```js
const data = [{ message: "Banana", path: "fruit" }, { message: "Volvo", path: "car"}, { message: "Cat", path: "animal" }];

const merge = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, o) => {
    acc[o.path] = o.message;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
console.log(merge(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build an object with the entries.

```js
const
    data = [{ item: "Banana", path: "fruit" }, { message: "Volvo", path: "car" }, { message: "Cat", path: "animal" }],
    object = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ item, message, path }) =>
        [path, item || message]
    ));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `.map` callback, return a *new object* (not just a property assignment), where the object's key is the `path` key in the object, and the value is the value of the first non-`path` key:

```js
const data = [
    {
        item: "Banana",
        path: "fruit"
    },
    {
        message: "Volvo",
        path: "car"
    },
    {
        message: "Cat",
        path: "animal"
    }
];

const newData = data.map(({ path, ...rest }) => ({
  [path]: Object.values(rest)[0]
}));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost perfect! It is a good approach to use the square brackets notation for this cases as you are doing.

You can achieve the result you are looking by filling the properties of an empty object instead of mapping the values. Like this:

```
var newData = {};

data.forEach(value => {
    newData[value.path] = value.message;
});
```

That is because your expected result is not an array (`var newData = []`), but an object (`var newData = {}`).